# An analytic function is onto

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

All sets are subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $f: U \to D$ is analytic where $U$ is bounded and open, and $D$ is the open unit disk.

Now suppose we can continuously extend $f$ to $\bar{f}: \bar{U} \to \bar D$, such that $\bar{f}(\partial U) \subseteq \partial D$.  To show that $f$ is onto, I was thinking maybe I could show that $f(U)$ is  a dense subset of $\bar{D}$ , and since $\bar{f}(U) = f(U)$ is open by the open mapping theorem, it must be $D$.  But to do this I would need to know that $f(\partial U) = \partial D$.  Is this true?

Some advice or other approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @julien I am trying to show that $f(U) = D$.

Comment: Right, thanks. You actually said it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f$ is not onto then $D$ containts a point $w$ which is on the boundary of $f(U)$. Take a sequence in $U$ with $f(z_k)\to w$, and use compactness.

Comment: By compactness of $\overline{U}$, we may assume wlog that $z_k$ converges to $z\in\overline{U}$. So $w$ belongs to $f(\overline{U})$. Not $f(U)$, so no contradiction. What did I miss?

Comment: There are two cases to consider: $z\in U$ or $z\in\partial U$.

Comment: Taking julien's approach, we conclude that $w \in \bar{f}(\bar{U}) = \bar{f}(U \cup \partial U)$, so $w \in f(\partial U) \subset \partial D$.  Is that the contradiction?

Comment: Right, got it. Am I slow...?

Comment: @user71954 That's Harald's approach. It's brilliant, and it took me one hour to figure it out. So by no means that's my approach. And yes, that's the contradiction.